# cambio numero 3 en raya

Tags: c

tengo que hacer un tres en raya y no me cambia la ficha en el sitio que se elige y no se por que dejo el codigo por aqui, gracias de antemano

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>



int main(){

    char j1[50];
    char j2[50];
    char numerost[2][2];
    char a,f1,f2;

    int i,j,fpre1,fpre2,lugar,n,aux;

do{

    {   //jugadores(hecho)

    system("cls");
    printf("bienvenidoa Tres en Raya.\n");
    printf("Presione una tecla para comenzar.\n");

    getch();
    system("cls");

    printf("Indique nombre del jugador 1:");
    //gets(j1);
    scanf("%s",&j1);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    printf("Indique nombre del jugador 2:");
    //gets(j2);
    scanf("%s",&j2);
    fflush(stdin);

    system("cls");

    }
    {   //eleccion ficha jugadores (hecho)
    {//jugador 1
    do{

        printf("%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j1);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.€.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre1);
            fflush(stdin);

        switch(fpre1){


            case 1:
                f1='X';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 2:
                f1='O';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 3:
                f1='€';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 4:
                f1='$';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;

            case 5:
                f1='@';
                fflush(stdin);
                break;


            default: printf("introduzca un numero valido");
                break;
    }
}
    while(0>fpre1||fpre1>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j1,f1);}

    {//jugador 2

    do{
        printf("%s,elija ficha con la que jugar.\n",j2);

        printf("1.X.\n");
        printf("2.O.\n");
        printf("3.€.\n");
        printf("4.$.\n");
        printf("5.@.\n");

            scanf("%d",&fpre2);
            fflush(stdin);



        switch(fpre2){

            case 1:
                f2='X';

                break;

            case 2:
                f2='O';

                break;

            case 3:
                f2='€';

                break;

            case 4:
                f2='$';

                break;

            case 5:
                f2='@';

                break;

            default: 
            printf("introduzca un numero valido\n");
                break;
        }
        if(fpre1==fpre2){
                printf("las fichas no pueden ser iguales.\n\n");
            }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    } 
    while(fpre1==fpre2||0>fpre2||fpre2>5);

    printf("%s jugara con %c\n\n",j2,f2);}




    }
    {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a='1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a++;
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }
    {   //colocacion de fichas 

    do{

        printf("Coloca la ficha.\n");
        scanf("%d",&aux);
        fflush(stdin);

    }while(aux<1||aux>9);


        switch(aux){
            case'1':
                i=0;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                break;  
            case'2':
                i=0;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'3':
                i=0;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;  
            case'4':
                i=1;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'5':
                i=1;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'6':
                i=1;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'7':
                i=2;
                j=0;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;
            case'8':
                i=2;
                j=1;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }       
                    break;
            case'9':
                i=2;
                j=2;
                if(numerost[i][j]==f1||numerost[i][j]==f2){
                    printf("La casilla esta ocupada.\n");
                    }
                    break;      

        }
        numerost[i][j]=f1;

        {   //tablero(hecho)
    {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
    a='1';
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                numerost[i][j]=a++;
            }
        }   
    }
    {   //tablero estructura(hecho)
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                if(j<2){

                printf(" %c|",numerost[i][j]);
                }

                else{
                    printf(" %c",numerost[i][j]);
                }

        }
        if(i<2){
        printf("\n---------");
        printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("\n");
        }   
            }

    }
    }       








    }
    {   //jugar otra vez
    printf("¿desea volver a jugar?\n");
    printf("1.Si.\n");
    printf("2.No.\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    }while(n==1); 

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Al margen de la estructura general del código, que es muy mejorable (tienes mucho código repetido, que podría sacarse a funciones, tienes bloques delimitados por llaves sin que se sepa por qué, ya que no son el cuerpo de ningún bucle ni condicional, etc.), tienes unos errores importantes que deberás resolver antes de seguir trabajando en tu solución. Son los siguientes:

1. La variable `aux` sobre la que lees la respuesta del jugador que indica qué casilla quiere jugar, ha sido declarada como `int`, y es leída correctamente como tal (`"%d"`) pero el `switch (aux)` que sigue trata la variable como tipo `char`, ya que los casos enumerados son `'1'`, `'2'`, etc. Debes quitar las comillas alrededor de esos casos.

   Mejor aún sería que en lugar de un `switch` con cantidad de código repetido, intentaras encontrar una fórmula que te permita calcular los valores de fila y columna a partir del número dado por el jugador. Por ejemplo, el cociente de dividir por 3 podría ser la fila, y el resto de la división podría ser la columna.
2. Una vez has almacenado la "ficha" del jugador en la casilla que éste te ha indicado, viene un bucle:

   ```
       {   //numeros tablero(hecho)
           a='1';
           for(i=0;i<3;i++){
               for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                   numerost[i][j]=a++;
               }
           }
      }
   ```

   Este código, además de tener esas inexplicables llaves delimitándolo, vuelven a sobreescribir las posiciones del array con los dígitos 1 a 9, borrando por tanto la jugada anterior. Elimina este trozo de código para que el tablero contenga correctamente la jugadas previa.

Por otro lado, entiendo que tras mostrar este tablero debería volver a pedir una jugada al segundo jugador, pero en lugar de eso el juego termina. Entiendo que aún estás trabajando sobre esta parte.